# setClickable() thwarted by onClickListener

Tags: android

In my main activity I have a button which I make clickable or non clickable according to a given state.   However I discover that the onClickListener automatically makes it clickable again!  So how to disable a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your `view` non-clickable:

view.setClickable(false);

If you want to disable your `view`:

view.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1):

Restore clickable after setting listener, for instance:

```
boolean isClickable = mView.isClickable();
mView.setOnClickListener(this);
mView.setClickable(isClickable);
```